# ERROR Error: "Uncaught (in promise): Error: Loading chunk xx failed

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, amazon-web-services, web-deployment

I have deployed my angular application in aws and when i access my site it will  show below error

```
    (missing: http://pxxxxxxxm.s3-wxexxbsite.xxxxx-1.amazonaws.com/9.5613f947b2a0944ac975.js)
    f@http://pxxxxxxxm.s3-wxexxbsite.xxxxx-1.amazonaws.com/runtime.153b2ec2879f01cfb905.js?cb=1567154111626&fingerprint=c2VwLW5vLXJlZGlyZWN0&onIframeFlag:1:1397
P@http://pxxxxxxxm.s3-wxexxbsite.xxxxx-1.amazonaws.com/polyfills.d1a2cbe0e30125ece580.js:1:19543
0TWp/</</s</t.prototype.invokeTask@http://pxxxxxxxm.s3-wxexxbsite.xxxxx-1.amazonaws.com/polyfills.d1a2cbe0e30125ece580.js:1:8845
onInvokeTask@http://pxxxxxxxm.s3-wxexxbsite.xxxxx-1.amazonaws.com/main.c55f72c755085c86d772.js:1:268861
0TWp/</</s</t.prototype.invokeTask@http://pxxxxxxxm.s3-wxexxbsite.xxxxx-1.amazonaws.com/polyfills.d1a2cbe0e30125ece580.js:1:8766
0TWp/</</a</e.prototype.runTask@http://pxxxxxxxm.s3-wxexxbsite.xxxxx-1.amazonaws.com/polyfills.d1a2cbe0e30125ece580.js:1:4027
0TWp/</</c</e.invokeTask@http://pxxxxxxxm.s3-wxexxbsite.xxxxx-1.amazonaws.com/polyfills.d1a2cbe0e30125ece580.js:1:9928
y@http://pxxxxxxxm.s3-wxexxbsite.xxxxx-1.amazonaws.com/polyfills.d1a2cbe0e30125ece580.js:1:23375
b@http://pxxxxxxxm.s3-wxexxbsite.xxxxx-1.amazonaws.com/polyfills.d1a2cbe0e30125ece580.js:1:23605
"
    M        http://pxxxxxxxm.s3-wxexxbsite.xxxxx-1.amazonaws.com/polyfills.d1a2cbe0e30125ece580.js:1
    M        http://pxxxxxxxm.s3-wxexxbsite.xxxxx-1.amazonaws.com/polyfills.d1a2cbe0e30125ece580.js:1
    N        http://pxxxxxxxm.s3-wxexxbsite.xxxxx-1.amazonaws.com/polyfills.d1a2cbe0e30125ece580.js:1
    invokeTask   http://pxxxxxxxm.s3-wxexxbsite.xxxxx-1.amazonaws.com/polyfills.d1a2cbe0e30125ece580.js:1
    onInvokeTask http://pxxxxxxxm.s3-wxexxbsite.xxxxx-1.amazonaws.com/main.c55f72c755085c86d772.js:1
    invokeTask   http://pxxxxxxxm.s3-wxexxbsite.xxxxx-1.amazonaws.com/polyfills.d1a2cbe0e30125ece580.js:1
    runTask      http://pxxxxxxxm.s3-wxexxbsite.xxxxx-1.amazonaws.com/polyfills.d1a2cbe0e30125ece580.js:1
    g        http://pxxxxxxxm.s3-wxexxbsite.xxxxx-1.amazonaws.com/polyfills.d1a2cbe0e30125ece580.js:1
    invokeTask   http://pxxxxxxxm.s3-wxexxbsite.xxxxx-1.amazonaws.com/polyfills.d1a2cbe0e30125ece580.js:1
    y        http://pxxxxxxxm.s3-wxexxbsite.xxxxx-1.amazonaws.com/polyfills.d1a2cbe0e30125ece580.js:1
    b        http://pxxxxxxxm.s3-wxexxbsite.xxxxx-1.amazonaws.com/polyfills.d1a2cbe0e30125ece580.js:1
main.c55f72c755085c86d772.js:1:251213
    Gt       http://pxxxxxxxm.s3-wxexxbsite.xxxxx-1.amazonaws.com/main.c55f72c755085c86d772.js:1
    handleError  http://pxxxxxxxm.s3-wxexxbsite.xxxxx-1.amazonaws.com/main.c55f72c755085c86d772.js:1
    next     http://pxxxxxxxm.s3-wxexxbsite.xxxxx-1.amazonaws.com/main.c55f72c755085c86d772.js:1
    o        http://pxxxxxxxm.s3-wxexxbsite.xxxxx-1.amazonaws.com/main.c55f72c755085c86d772.js:1
    __tryOrUnsub http://pxxxxxxxm.s3-wxexxbsite.xxxxx-1.amazonaws.com/main.c55f72c755085c86d772.js:1
    next     http://pxxxxxxxm.s3-wxexxbsite.xxxxx-1.amazonaws.com/main.c55f72c755085c86d772.js:1
    _next    http://pxxxxxxxm.s3-wxexxbsite.xxxxx-1.amazonaws.com/main.c55f72c755085c86d772.js:1
    next     http://pxxxxxxxm.s3-wxexxbsite.xxxxx-1.amazonaws.com/main.c55f72c755085c86d772.js:1
    next     http://pxxxxxxxm.s3-wxexxbsite.xxxxx-1.amazonaws.com/main.c55f72c755085c86d772.js:1
    emit     http://pxxxxxxxm.s3-wxexxbsite.xxxxx-1.amazonaws.com/main.c55f72c755085c86d772.js:1
    onHandleError http://pxxxxxxxm.s3-wxexxbsite.xxxxx-1.amazonaws.com/main.c55f72c755085c86d772.js:1
    invoke   http://pxxxxxxxm.s3-wxexxbsite.xxxxx-1.amazonaws.com/polyfills.d1a2cbe0e30125ece580.js:1
    run      http://pxxxxxxxm.s3-wxexxbsite.xxxxx-1.amazonaws.com/polyfills.d1a2cbe0e30125ece580.js:1
    runOutsideAngular http://pxxxxxxxm.s3-wxexxbsite.xxxxx-1.amazonaws.com/main.c55f72c755085c86d772.js:1
    onHandleError http://pxxxxxxxm.s3-wxexxbsite.xxxxx-1.amazonaws.com/main.c55f72c755085c86d772.js:1
    handleError   http://pxxxxxxxm.s3-wxexxbsite.xxxxx-1.amazonaws.com/polyfills.d1a2cbe0e30125ece580.js:1
    runGuarded    http://pxxxxxxxm.s3-wxexxbsite.xxxxx-1.amazonaws.com/polyfills.d1a2cbe0e30125ece580.js:1
    t             http://pxxxxxxxm.s3-wxexxbsite.xxxxx-1.amazonaws.com/polyfills.d1a2cbe0e30125ece580.js:1
    microtaskDrainDone http://pxxxxxxxm.s3-wxexxbsite.xxxxx-1.amazonaws.com/polyfills.d1a2cbe0e30125ece580.js:1
    g            http://pxxxxxxxm.s3-wxexxbsite.xxxxx-1.amazonaws.com/polyfills.d1a2cbe0e30125ece580.js:1
    invokeTask   http://pxxxxxxxm.s3-wxexxbsite.xxxxx-1.amazonaws.com/polyfills.d1a2cbe0e30125ece580.js:1
    y            http://pxxxxxxxm.s3-wxexxbsite.xxxxx-1.amazonaws.com/polyfills.d1a2cbe0e30125ece580.js:1
    b            http://pxxxxxxxm.s3-wxexxbsite.xxxxx-1.amazonaws.com/polyfills.d1a2cbe0e30125ece580.js:1
```

When I reload all files load correctly, but sometimes when I open the site again, the same error are shown and I have to refresh again.

build cmd - `ng build --prod`

**Versions**

Angular CLI: 6.2.9

Node: 10.14.1

OS: win32 x64

Angular: 6.1.10

webpack : 4.9.2

I have put my dist folder in my localserver apache and its working perfectly.

Comment: https://medium.com/@kamrankhatti/angular-lazy-routes-loading-chunk-failed-42b16c22a377